# Frequency of photon from decaying particle in Lab Frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, frequency

A particle of rest mass M, while at rest in the laboratory, decays into a particle of mass $m$ and speed $v$, and a photon of frequency $f$ moving in opposite direction. Relativistic momentum and energy is conserved in this process.

I'm looking to find the frequency of the photon in the lab frame.

My prediction is that $hf=\frac {Mvc^2}{c+v}$ but I cannot seem to verify this.

**Momentum Conservation**: $0=\frac{hf}{c} - \gamma(v)mv$

**Energy Conservation**: $Mc^2=hf+\gamma(v)mc^2$

And I have since shown that $m=M\sqrt {\frac{c-v}{c+v}}$

Are these the correct equations for the Lab Frame or am I making a mistake here.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor? Or is this a question on a test?  Do you think this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This was just a simple re-arrangement problem which I think I have since solved.

If $Mc^2=\gamma(v)mvc+\gamma(v)mc^2$

$Mc^2=\gamma(v)mc(v+c)$

$\frac{Mc}{v+c}=\gamma(v)m$

using $0=\frac{hf}{c}-\gamma(v)mv$

We get $hf=\gamma(v)mvc$

And that gives $hf=\frac{Mc}{v+c}*cv$

gives, $hf=\frac{Mc^2v}{c+v}$