# Energy and momentum conservation equations for frame moving at speed $v$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics, inertial-frames

> A particle of rest mass $M$, while at rest in the laboratory, decays into a particle of mass $m$ and speed $v$, and a photon of frequency $f$ moving in opposite direction.

I want to look at this problem in the frame moving at speed $v$.

How could I determine the momentum and energy conservation equations here.

**My Understanding**: This would cause the particle of mass $m$ to be stationary hence its speed would now be $0$, and the photon released in the opposite direction would appear to travel at double the speed.

I'm unsure about how to form the required equations. I am also aware that $m=M\sqrt{\frac{c-v}{c+v}}$ regardless of the frame.

I tried working back from this point but I just got the equations corresponding to the frame where the particle $M$ is stationary.

Any help would be great as I'll need the energy and momentum equations to do further proofs.

Comment: The photon can't travel at double speed! It *has* to travel at $c$ in *every* inertial frame.

Comment: Of course. Such a silly error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/541887/2451

Comment: Any help regarding the conservation equations here would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: @Student146 Try to write the energy and momentum conservation equations. You can search online about the momentum conservation